# Team collaboration with Maven - Java EE

Tags: java, project-management, java-ee, maven

For team of 6,

We have *spring MVC* project being developed with Angular as Frontend and Spring framework as back end.

---

From Java project build & version control aspect,

Is it recommended, to **not restrict** the team on using specific editor, by creating the maven template(spring mvc archetype) and share java code on github, for any user to download that code from github and allow to use any editor like IntelliJ or eclipse with corresponding editor plugin of maven?

or

Is it recommended, **to restrict** the team to use specific editor(say eclipse) and create eclipse project with maven plugin installed in eclipse?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's any **recommended** way to go.

That said, as a developer, I would hate a company where the IDE choice is imposed. Developers are more productive and happy with their favourite tools.

Also try not to be locked into an IDE. You could regret it in the future, imagine if next year some company delivers a new IDE with many killer-features, why wouldn't you try it?

Answer (score 3):

My preferred option is:

- command line maven and CI is the reference and should always work
- if you have code conventions, everybody need to respect them (practically: be nice and have formatting conventions and warning settings that can be implemented well within all desired IDEs)
- each IDE sub community is free to also check in their .project, .idea or other code templates as long as they don't break any of the rules above